# DistributedSampler — Expected a ‘cuda’ device type for generator when generating indices

Tags: python, pytorch, distributed-computing

Performing distributed training, I have the following code like this:

```
training_sampler = DistributedSampler(training_set, num_replicas=2, rank=0)
training_generator = data.DataLoader(training_set, **params, sampler=training_sampler)
for x, y, z in training_generator:  # Error occurs here.
    ...
```

Overall, I get the following message:

```
-- Process 0 terminated with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 19, in _wrap
    fn(i, *args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/VC/ppg_training_extraction/ppg_training_scripts/train_ASR_trim_scp.py", line 336, in train
    for local_batch_src, local_batch_tgt, lengths in dataloaders[phase]:
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 352, in __iter__
    return self._get_iterator()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 294, in _get_iterator
    return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 827, in __init__
    self._reset(loader, first_iter=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 857, in _reset
    self._try_put_index()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1091, in _try_put_index
    index = self._next_index()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 427, in _next_index
    return next(self._sampler_iter)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py", line 227, in __iter__
    for idx in self.sampler:
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/distributed.py", line 97, in __iter__
    indices = torch.randperm(len(self.dataset), generator=g).tolist()  # type: ignore
RuntimeError: Expected a 'cuda' device type for generator but found 'cpu'
```

Now at that line, I ran the following instructions in pdb:

```
(Pdb) g = torch.Generator()
(Pdb) g.manual_seed(0)
<torch._C.Generator object at 0x7ff7f8143110>
(Pdb) indices = torch.randperm(4556, generator=g).tolist()
(Pdb) indices = torch.randperm(455604, generator=g).tolist()
*** RuntimeError: Expected a 'cuda' device type for generator but found 'cpu'
```

Why am I getting the runtime error when the upperbound integer is high, but not when it’s low enough?

Note, I ran on a clean Python session and found

```
>>> import torch
>>> g = torch.Generator()
>>> g.manual_seed(0)
<torch._C.Generator object at 0x7f9d2dfb39f0>
>>> indices = torch.randperm(455604, generator=g).tolist()
```

that this worked fine. Is it some configuration in how I’m handling distributed training among multiple GPUs? Any sort of insights would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I just met the same problem using dataloader and I found the following helps without removing torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')

`data.DataLoader(..., generator=torch.Generator(device='cuda'))`

since I don't want to manually add .to('cuda') for tons of tensors in my code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Looks like somebody found the source of the problem [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/distributedsampler-runtimeerror-expected-a-cuda-device-type-for-generator-but-found-cpu/103594):

```py
torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')
```

I fixed my problem by getting rid of this line in my code and manually using `.to(device)`.